# Can $f^{(\infty)}(a)=0$ for almost all $a$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, derivatives

My question is:

> Does there exist an infinitely differentiable function $f$ such that
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty} f^{(n)}(a)=0\qquad{\text{for almost all } a\in[0,\infty)}$$
>   ?

($f$ cannot be a constant function or a polynomial.)

---

If we restrict us to $C^{\omega}$ (i.e. assuming $f$ is holomorphic), it is likely that the answer is no, since
$$f^{(n)}(a)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\oint_{\gamma}\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}dz$$
the integrand only decays exponentially in $n$ while there is a $n!$ factor there.

---

However, I am not quite sure if the above argument is correct.

For smooth functions, I have no ideas.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear to me what "almost all" means.

Comment: @JohnOmielan it is a term used in Lebesgue measure theory. You can find the explanation of this term on Wikipedia.

Comment: fundamental theorem of calculus applied to the derivatives of $f$ along with the almost everywhere assumption and dominated convergence may lead to something (?). not entirely sure, just throwing out an idea

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try $$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{(k!)^2} = I_0(2 \sqrt{x})$$
This is an entire function, and
$$ f^{(n)}(x) = \sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{x^{k-n}}{k! (k-n)!} = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{x^j}{(j+n)! j!} $$
so that for all $x$
$$ |f^{(n)}(x)| \le \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{|x|^j}{(j+n)! j!} \le \frac{1}{n!} \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{x^j}{j!} = \frac{\exp(|x|)}{n!}$$
and thus $f^{(n)}(x) \to 0$ for all $x$.

Comment: What about $\sin(x/2)$ or $e^{x/2}$.

Comment: Those work too, and much simpler.